# How to subtract multiple string values from another string

Tags: python

With:

```
abc = 'abc'
xyz = 'xyz'

word = 'begin abc- middle_xyz_ end'
```

I need to extract the values of `abc` and `xyz` from `word`.
The result should be

```
result = 'begin - middle__ end'
```

How to achieve this with a minimum amount of code?

Comment: see `re.sub` from `re` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `replace()` with an empty string as the value to replace with.

```
result = word.replace('abc','').replace('xyz','')
```